# How to connect an android app running on a device connected via ADB to hit REST API on local server?

Tags: android, spring-mvc, localhost, retrofit2

I have a multi-tenant  web app like

```
http://xxxxx.constant-domain.com:8080/
```

in my host file

```
127.0.0.1       xxxxx.constant-domain.com
```

The device that has the android app running is connected via `ADB` which calls my webapp's Rest Apis to get and send data and
It runs fine on dev and prod environments like 
`http://xxxxx.dev.constant-domain.com/get-data`
 but the problem is I want to debug it on my local server. I tried adding the given domain as base url but it doesn't work.
I tried adding `http://localhost:8080/` as well but it doesn't work.
I tried looking for questions here but didn't find anything that would help.
I'm using **retrofit** for Api calls.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. All I needed to do was to set my private Ip as

```
http://192.168.8.400:8080/get-data
```

Hope this helps anyone who is in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that your local server and your device are using a same wifi. And then find out the option to put your local server online. There is an option in Wamp Server to put it online. I don't know which software you are using to setup apache or any kind of server on your computer.

And then you will be able to access your local server by ip address. Also there is an option to edit virtual hosts of your server to allocate a specific port that the app can connect.

It doesn't matter whether you use Retrofit or Volley or Okhttp or any other things. You need to setup your local server to be online within your local network.

Comment: The OP is using Spring-MVC not PHP :)

Comment: @kenny as shashanth said the post is not using wamp. the internet is same and I tried looking into putting the server online Didn't quite find anything to do that... what do you say?